# After scraping multiple elements through scraping i could able to export only one row to my data frame result instead 560

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, for-loop

```
This is my code , where i am scraping multiple elements from the webpage through for loop using beautiful soup and list comprehension.
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Address', 'Phone', 'Established_On', 'Local_comp_id','Share_capital'])
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
results= soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'jss255'})
time.sleep(2)
for result in results:
    name = [i.text for i in result.find_all('div', {'class': 'MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 css-p5i4ju'})][0]
    address = [i.text for i in result.find_all('p', {'class': 'MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 css-1pzoy6j'})][2]
    phone = [i.text for i in result.find_all('p', {'class': 'MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 css-1pzoy6j'})][1]
    established_on = [i.text for i in result.find_all('div', {'class': 'MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 css-p5i4ju'})][8]
    local_comp_id = [i.text for i in result.find_all('div', {'class': 'MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 css-p5i4ju'})][1]
    share_capital = [i.text for i in result.find_all('div', {'class': 'MuiTypography-root MuiTypography-body2 css-p5i4ju'})][10]
    time.sleep(3)
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [name], 'Address':[address], 'Phone':[phone], 'Established_On':[established_on], 'Local_comp_id':[local_comp_id],'Share_capital': [share_capital]})
    df = df.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)
    #temp_df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [name for j in name], 'Address':[address for k in address], 'Phone':[phone for l in phone], 'Established_On':[established_on for m in established_on], 'Local_comp_id':[local_comp_id for n in local_comp_id],'Share_capital': [share_capital for o in share_capital]})
    #df = df.append(temp_df, ignore_index=True)
```

driver.quit()

Instead of only one row output i am expecting multiple rows.